# Fan dimmer switch wiring

Tags: wiring

Old fan dimmer switch has red black and blue, new switch 
Has yellow red and black plus a green ground . How do I rewrite?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the switch box please?  Also, what make and model was the old fan control, and what make and model is the new fan control?

Comment: We can't possibly guess. **There is no standard whatsoever for Hot colors in electrical wiring** and all those wires are hot.   We would need to figure it out from the way wires are presently arranged, the markings on the old device, and the markings and instructions on the new one. [Edit] in photos of the in-box wiring, present connections to old device, and model number of the new one...

Comment: Didn't the new switch come with instructions?

Comment: Sounds like a device that is not UL listed from a source like China.